# Setting jquery mouseovers to access array keys in a javascript loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

In my loop IDs are assigned correctly with x, but when i try to assign an array function with x it throws an error 'this method is undefined'. I was just wondering how to structure this type of dynamic mousover correctly? Any help would be amazing! Many thanks, Joe

```
for (x = 0; x < mapEastData.length; x++) {
    $('#marker' + x).on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            mapEastMarkers[x].setVisible(true);
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            mapEastMarkers[x].setVisible(false);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML you have as this seems a very odd way of attaching handlers. Could you not have a `class` which you assign a handler too and then traverse the DOM to get the relevent `mapEastMarkers` element?

Comment: thanks that sounds like a much better way to do this

Comment: Hey Joe why didn't you put your HTML markup, Heeey Joe listen to what Rory says ... :)

Comment: they are google maps markers in an array..

Comment: The class if I remember correctly is `gmnoprint`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would opt to use a class rather than an id to trigger your hover.

So use a class, say `marker-class` as your hover selector.

Then in the mouseenter / mouseleave functions you should be able to get access to the id of that exact element using something like: 
`$(this).attr('id').replace("marker" , "")`

The replace then cleans the ID so you end up with the id number.

I hope this makes sense to you. I think the issue with your current code is that the mouseenter/leave functions have no idea what the var X is. IF you want to stick with your current approach you may need to pass your x parameter into those functions.